# Unexpected results from Java DOM getAttribute

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am having some trouble with my DOM parser for Java. I am trying to parse the entire XML document and save everything into either Strings or ArrayLists depending how it appears in the document. Right now I have run into one issue in particular. I am trying to parse the attribute of a child value of an element here:

```
-<Ntfctn>

      <Id>161RD2521JI00XSZ</Id>

      <CreDtTm>2016-01-27T13:25:21</CreDtTm>

      +<Acct>

      +<TxsSummry>

      +<Ntry xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.04">
```

As you can see there are two elements under Ntfctn that contain attributes, Id and CreDtTm. Right now all I really need is "Id". I have already collected the credit amount earlier in my code. There are numerous "Id" tags throughout the XML so calling "Id" directly won't work.

I have tried calling the attribute in this way:

```
NodeList Ntfctn = doc.getElementsByTagName("Ntfctn");

            for(int temp = 0; temp < MsgRcpt.getLength(); temp++){
                System.out.println(Ntfctn.item(0).getAttributes());
            }
```

But get some unexpected results

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttributeMap@2a139a55
```

I've tried changing the Ntfctn.get value to several numbers but none seem to pull what I am looking for. Other areas of my code have worked perfectly. I will post the entire thing below.

Please let me know the proper way for me to get the value from an attribute that has the same name across the file.

```
package parsing;

import java.io.File;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.*;

public class XMLParser 

{

    public static String CreDtTmS;
    public static String MsgIdS; 
    public static String MsgRcptS;
    public static String NtfctnS;

    public void parseXML(){

        try{

            File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\jhamric\\Desktop\\Camt54.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList CreDtTm = doc.getElementsByTagName("CreDtTm");

            for(int temp = 0; temp < CreDtTm.getLength(); temp++){
                CreDtTmS = CreDtTm.item(0).getTextContent();
            }

            NodeList MsgId = doc.getElementsByTagName("MsgId");

            for(int temp = 0; temp < MsgId.getLength(); temp++){
                MsgIdS = MsgId.item(0).getTextContent();
            }

            NodeList MsgRcpt = doc.getElementsByTagName("MsgRcpt");

            for(int temp = 0; temp < MsgRcpt.getLength(); temp++){
                MsgRcptS = MsgRcpt.item(0).getTextContent();
            }

            NodeList Ntfctn = doc.getElementsByTagName("Ntfctn");

            for(int temp = 0; temp < MsgRcpt.getLength(); temp++){
                System.out.println(Ntfctn.item(0).getAttributes());
            }


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("GrpHdr -> CreDtTm: "+CreDtTmS);
        System.out.println("GrpHdr -> MsgId: "+MsgIdS);
        System.out.println("GrpHdr -> MsgRcpt -> Id -> OrgId -> Othr -> Id: "+MsgRcptS);


    }

}
```

The question was answered using help from the accepted answer below.

After trial and error this was the bit of code that worked:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
            XPath xPath =XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Ntfctn/Id");
            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
            System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
            for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){
                Element el = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                System.out.println("Tag: "+ el.getNodeName());
                System.out.println(el.getTextContent());
            }
```

Comment: `As you can see there are two elements under Ntfctn that contain attributes, Id and CreDtTm.` No, they don't contain attributes. They contain text nodes, which can be obtained via `Node.getTextContent()` for example.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], with an actual XML document (not how it appears in a browser, with the extra + and - bits; load it in a text editor). The code you've posted so far isn't minimal or complete. Please help us to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry Jon Skeet but due to the nature of my job I can't post the entire XML sheet. It is actually payment records so obviously I can't share. I had hoped that was enough to illustrate my point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refine your selection you can use xpath:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("//Ntfctn/Id",
        doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: I seem to get an error when I try to do that, the possible solutions are to import a package (not sure which one) or change it to newInstance().newXPathAPI.. Suggestions?

Comment: Import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory

Comment: I imported the factory as you suggested and the code exactly as you have it above but I get an errorthat "XPath canno't be resolved to a type"

Comment: Thanks. I needed some extra stuff but you got me far enough to figure it out. Thanks for your help!!